# Adding Firebase via importing SDK (not CocoaPods) causes file not found exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, admob, firebase-analytics

I am attempting to add Firebase to my iOS project via importing the SDK instead of using CocoaPods (I'm not a fan).

I have followed the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup) but I am getting file not found error.

[image]

I have cleaned, deleted, restarted, re-imported, re-did the instructions SEVERAL times and I keep getting this error.

Has anyone succesfully imported the Firebase SDK into an iOS project?

Added to the projects directory:

[image]

The frameworks auto-added themselves to the `Linked Frameworks`

[image]

Added the `-ObjC` to `Other linker flags`

[image]

But still the file not found error:

[image]

**Any help?**

Inside the frameworks:

[image]

Pastebin of the Build file: [PASTBIN](https://pastebin.com/Sb03eWaQ)

Comment: try Carthage.  cocoapods is useless now.

Comment: Can you show the expanded FirebaseAnalytics.framework folder? I just want to see if it even contains the FirebaseAnalytics.h file.

Comment: Try deleting the ModuleCache - rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/

Comment: That didn't work @PaulBeusterien

Comment: What is your SDK version? Did you download the latest one?

Comment: It is version 3.17.0 @adbitx

Comment: I got rid of a similar problem by adding a import to my objc bridging header. #import "Firebase.h" But then I got other issues in runtime when calling configure() as startup.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the Firebase SDK to the root directory and later move them to the frameworks folder.